# TCPClient not connecting after selecting ip from Dns.GetHostAddresses

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I feel like an idiot here, I'm also on a time sensitive mission right now.

```
                {
                IPAddress[] hostEntry = Dns.GetHostAddresses(cnc);

                //you might get more than one ip for a hostname since 
                //DNS supports more than one record

                for (var i = 0; i < hostEntry.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(hostEntry[i].ToString());
                    NetworkStream stream;
                    StreamReader reader;
                    StreamWriter writer;
                    string data;
                    using (var client = new TcpClient(hostEntry[i].ToString(), 6697))
                    {
```

Now why isnt this connecting to my irc server? when I sit there and longingly stare at process hacker my connection is stuck on syn_sent when my server is online, unfirewalled into oblivion here.

Comment: Is it a problem with your code or networking? Can you confirm you can connect using `netcat` or similar?

Comment: yes, I can confirm, the same code doesnt even work with google. com on port 80

Comment: Still feels more networking related.  Have you tried `netcat`?  Also, TcpClient takes a hostname so you don't even need to resolve the address yourself.

Comment: I only seem to be able to connect to ip address string literals, not domains.